# How do I bring the entry box closer to the names in html?

Tags: html

I am trying to bring the entry fields closer to the names; it looks bit far. wanted to see if anybody can suggest. Html and css are shown below. This is how it looks now:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>Add Student</h3>
  <form action="StudentControllerServlet" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="ADD" />

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label>First name:</label></td>   
          <td> <input type="text" name="firstName"/></td>                               
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><label>Last name:</label></td>    
           <td><input type="text" name="lastName"/></td>                                
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><label>Email:</label></td>    
          <td> <input type="text" name="email" /></td>                              
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Define a `width` for each of the first `<td>` elements in each `<tr>`.

Comment: Do you have css setting the width to 100% somewhere? If so you might include it in your example since when I moved it to the snippet editor it doesn't reflect your screenshot.

Comment: someone edited the code and I guess your issue is solved

Comment: @ObsidianAge: I have added <tr>
      <td><label>First name:</label></td> 
      <td> <input type="text" name="firstName" width="10"/></td>        
     </tr>, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Ashishsah nah it wasn't edited, it just didn't have his css included.

Answer (score 3):

```css
/* To mimic your screenshot */
#container table {
  width: 50%;
  outline: red 1px dotted;
}

/* To align your text closer */
#container table td:first-child  {
  outline: green 1px dashed;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>Add Student</h3>
  <form action="StudentControllerServlet" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="ADD" />

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label>First name:</label></td>   
          <td> <input type="text" name="firstName"/></td>                               
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><label>Last name:</label></td>    
           <td><input type="text" name="lastName"/></td>                                
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><label>Email:</label></td>    
          <td> <input type="text" name="email" /></td>                              
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: some reason mine is still have bit distance even after I used your css. I see your looks how  I want mine to look.

Comment: @pj_max do you have other css you didn't include in your example that's perhaps influencing your instance? If I can see it reproduced we can sort you out quick. If you edit your question you'll see a "edit this snippet" link under your snippet that will open the snippet editor where you can add everything.

Comment: I am trying to include CSS , but I am having trouble adding it. Keep showing me "red" error when I pasting it in the original question.

Comment: Are you adding it to the area for CSS in the snippet editor? Top right box?

Comment: yes, I pasted it, but when I try to save and post it, I see a red dot error.

Comment: I just pated the css. sorry about the messed up format. no way I could add css other than the picture.

Comment: okay, I have pasted both css now.

Comment: @pj_max haha nah, not screenshots, paste the actual code into the snippet editor in the CSS area so it can be used in the live example and we can edit it easily and reproduce your example please. I see several things in there that are invalid or redundant etc.

Comment: sorry Chris, I tried to paste the css in the editor, but I was keep getting error(red dot).

Comment: When you paste it into the top-right `CSS` box of the snippet editor? (the html will be top left box) and then hit "Run" you should see the example square (bottom right) display the rendered output then just hit "save and insert to post" button and save your edit. Not sure what you mean by red dot, sorry. Either way apologies but I don't have time to copy your screenshots into editable CSS before I head to bed :)

Comment: If you can paste your CSS in the same way you did your html originally then myself or someone else can move it to do the editor for ya. I'll take another peek in the morning, it's bedtime in my time zone. Cheers!